# validations for a table of Input Fields

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a series of Input Fields(Name,Quantity,Price) in table format in Visualforce page. By below JS i can validate if fields doesn't have any text by using their 'StyleClass(requires)':

```
function doOrderValid()
{
     var t = 0;
     jQuery('.requires').each(function(){
         var req = jQuery(this).val();
             if(req == '')
             {
                 t=t+1;
                 alert('Eneter fileds');
                 jQuery(this).focus();
                 return false;
             }

     });

}
```

any ideas on how to add extra validations for Name(its length should be greater than 2 and less than 20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first assign a class to `Name` field so that it can be accessed in your JS. (or use some other selector in jQuery)

```
function doOrderValid()
{
    var t = 0;
     // first make sure every required field is filled in
    jQuery('.requires').each(function () {
        var req = jQuery(this).val();
        if (req == '')
        {
            t = t + 1;
            alert('Eneter fileds');
            jQuery(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // now check if names are valid or not
    jQuery('.name').each(function(){
        var name = jQuery(this).val();
        if(name.length <2 || name.length > 20)
        {
            t=t+1;
            alert('Name value must be betweem 2 to 20 chareacters long.');
            jQuery(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You #shoaib. i added an extra class name and got it!! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add check for length of text

```
function doOrderValid()
{
     var t = 0;
     jQuery('.requires').each(function(){
         var req = jQuery(this).val();
             if(req == '' || !(req.length() > 2 && req.length() < 20))
             {
                 t=t+1;
                 alert('Eneter fileds');
                 jQuery(this).focus();
                 return false;
             }

     });

}
```

Comment: as per your code, it will checks price and quantity length too . they both can have a length of size 1